# Core-Plot graph not showing any data points

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, graph, core-plot

I've been able to get the axes for a standard core-plot graph to show up, but I'm having some trouble actually adding points to it.

I have these two methods declared in the .m file (found from another question on this site):

```
-(NSUInteger)numberOfRecordsForPlot:(CPTPlot *)plot;


-(NSNumber *)numberForPlot:(CPTPlot *)plot field:(NSUInteger)fieldEnum recordIndex:
```

So, at the top of that controller.m file, I have this:

```
NSArray *myDataArray;
```

Lastly, in the viewDidLoad method (still .m file), near the end (after creating the graph), I have an array with points set up.

When I build and run, XCode gives 0 errors or warnings, but the points do not show up on the graph.

Would appreciate any help, thanks!

Comment: Do you have the delegate protocols declared in the header file?  For example, if you are using a bar graph, you should have `CPBarPlotDelegate` and `CPPlotDataSource` in the header.  Otherwise, those methods above do not get called.  Hopefully that's the problem.  Otherwise, we'll have to do a little more digging

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I thought this would be too confusing to read in the comments, so I'm moving to an answer.

In your `numberForPlot` method, try something like the following:

```
- (NSNumber *)numberForPlot:(CPPlot *)plot field:(NSUInteger)fieldEnum recordIndex:(NSUInteger)index { 
    if (fieldEnum == CPScatterPlotFieldX) {
        // should return data for x axis point;
        return [[myDataArray objectAtIndex:index] objectAtIndex:index];
    }
    else {
        // y axis point;
        return [NSDecimalNumber numberWithInt:index];
    }
}
```

I apologize if it's pretty crude.  I just rewrote a bit from a bar graph to scatter plot.  But this should do the trick.  I think the issue was that you were calling `objectAtIndex:fieldEnum`.  This had me confused for a while also when I first started using CorePlot.  Again, if this doesn't do the trick, just say so and we'll try something new.  But I believe this should do it, or something very similar.

EDIT: In the example code provided with CorePlot, here is the code for the data itself:

```
-(NSNumber *)numberForPlot:(CPPlot *)plot field:(NSUInteger)fieldEnum recordIndex:(NSUInteger)index {
    NSDecimalNumber *num = nil;
    if ( [plot isKindOfClass:[CPPieChart class]] ) {
        if ( index >= [self.dataForChart count] ) return nil;

        if ( fieldEnum == CPPieChartFieldSliceWidth ) {
            num = [self.dataForChart objectAtIndex:index];
        }
        else {
            num = (NSDecimalNumber *)[NSDecimalNumber numberWithUnsignedInteger:index];
        }
    }
    else if ( [plot isKindOfClass:[CPBarPlot class]] ) {
        switch ( fieldEnum ) {
        case CPBarPlotFieldBarLocation:
            if ( index == 4 ) {
                num = [NSDecimalNumber notANumber];
            }
            else {
                num = (NSDecimalNumber *)[NSDecimalNumber numberWithUnsignedInteger:index];
            }
            break;
        case CPBarPlotFieldBarTip:
            if ( index == 8 ) {
                num = [NSDecimalNumber notANumber];
            }
            else {
                num = (NSDecimalNumber *)[NSDecimalNumber numberWithUnsignedInteger:(index+1)*(index+1)];
                if ( [plot.identifier isEqual:@"Bar Plot 2"] ) {
                    num = [num decimalNumberBySubtracting:[NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"10"]];
                }
            }
            break;
        }
    }
    else {
        if ( index % 8 ) {
            num = [[dataForPlot objectAtIndex:index] valueForKey:(fieldEnum == CPScatterPlotFieldX ? @"x" : @"y")];
            // Green plot gets shifted above the blue
            if ( [(NSString *)plot.identifier isEqualToString:@"Green Plot"] ) {
                if ( fieldEnum == CPScatterPlotFieldY ) {
                    num = (NSDecimalNumber *)[NSDecimalNumber numberWithDouble:[num doubleValue] + 1.0];
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            num = [NSDecimalNumber notANumber];
        }
    }
    return num;
}
```

Sorry for including all of it, but I thought it might make it easier to look at all of the types to better differentiate how to approach the scatter plot.  Creating their data, it looks like this:

```
NSMutableArray *contentArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:100];
NSUInteger i;
for ( i = 0; i < 60; i++ ) {
    id x = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1+i*0.05];
    id y = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.2*rand()/(float)RAND_MAX + 1.2];
    [contentArray addObject:[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:x, @"x", y, @"y", nil]];
}
self.dataForPlot = contentArray;
```

So maybe if you try a format like that, it could work.  If that doesn't do the trick, then we know it's an issue with the graph creation itself and not the data

Comment: Thank you again for the reply, I really appreciate it.  I changed slightly the first two lines of your code (CPTPlot instead of CPPlot, etc).  Unfortunately, though, the same problem persists.  Could it be perhaps the way I'm declaring the array, or is that a fairly standard way to do it?  Also, do these two functions need to be prototyped any special way in the .h file?  Thanks again!

Comment: Sorry about that.  I thought I got all the bar graph jargon out and replaced for scatter plot.  Oops.  There isn't anything special you need to do for the header file, no.  These methods are included in the delegate methods declared in CorePlot, so there is nothing to worry about there.  It is possible that it expects a different format for the array, but I doubt it.  Just to be safe, you can try declaring the objects as `[NSNumber numberWithFloat:...]` or as `NSDecimalNumber`.  Just out of curiosity, are these methods being called?  It might be a good idea to set up `NSLog`s to make sure

Comment: I've been looking just about everywhere to try and figure out what is going on here.  The code, to me, looks fine.  The only difference I can really see between your code and that in some of the sample CorePlot projects is that for scatter plots, they use NSDictionary to specify the scatter plot data in the array.  I'm going to edit my answer to add code from their example

Comment: My fingers are crossed.  Best of luck!

Comment: Checking the field enum was my issue. Thanks!